# Is it possible to configure secure(SSL) kafka with Telegraf?

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, ssl-certificate, telegraf, telegraf-output-plugins

Started working with TICK stack, I'm quite new to this. A dedicated machine is assigned for TICK to run and receive data. To begin with I have sent metrics from 3 instances to TICK stack using udp and everything is good. Now, I would like to send the `Kafka` information too, which is a secure(ssl-certified). Secure certificates came with files: `ca-cert`, `ca-cert.srl`, `ca-key`, `cert-file`, `cert-signed`, `kafka.client.truststore.jks`,  `kafka.server.keystore.jks`,  `kafka.server.truststore.jks`.

On the other end, I'm trying to configure telegraf.conf file with TSL config parameters for

```
tls_ca = "ca-cert"
tls_cert = "cert-signed" 
tls_key = "ca-key"
```

On starting telegraf the error shown is:

> 2019-01-18T11:51:48Z E! [agent] Failed to connect to output kafka, retrying in 15s, error was 'could not load keypair cert-signed:ca-key: tls: failed to parse private key'
>
> 2019-01-18T11:52:03Z E! [telegraf] Error running agent: could not load keypair cert-signed:ca-key: tls: failed to parse private key

Not sure what's going on. Help me debug or pick right files.
I understand that `kafka.client.truststore.jks` is used while any of the client try to access kafka.

But how is that used here, being telegraf is a client trying to publish?

Comment: JKS files are for the Java keystore. Since Telegraf doesn't use the Java clients, probably not needed

Comment: @cricket_007 not required is not valid i believe. While the Kafka instance is secure, producer/consumer would not allow the client to communicate with the server with out the encryption/decryption policy.

Comment: Telegraf uses Sarama client. https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/plugins/outputs/kafka/kafka.go#L15 And I don't see JKS being used or configured here https://medium.com/processone/using-tls-authentication-for-your-go-kafka-client-3c5841f2a625

Comment: Your error says it failed to parse the keys, so you should show how you generated them. But it is possible, based on this config section https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/plugins/outputs/kafka/kafka.go#L151-L156

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It turned out it was just a simple file permission issue for me. I had to change certificate and key file owner:group to Telegraf and it started working